# Spring Batch AWS S3 Resources - Connection Reset during processing

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application that is expected to read large csvs (200mb each in size) from AWS S3 and write the data into our database. We updated our process slightly to accommodate a new csv schema. When running this new import process using LocalStack, everything works flawlessly. As soon as we introduce a real network, we start having issues. When running the same process in our deployed environment, we get the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:328)
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:355)
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:808)
    at java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readFully(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:467)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:243)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1513)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1484)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1069)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.read(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:176)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.read(LengthCheckInputStream.java:107)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream.read(S3AbortableInputStream.java:125)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:270)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:313)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:177)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:162)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:207)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.NonTransientFlatFileException: Unable to read from resource: [Amazon s3 resource [bucket='bucket-name-here' and object='import/test.csv']]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:226)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader.read(SynchronizedItemStreamReader.java:57)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$987ea09.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a78c69a.read(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException: Non-skippable exception during read
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:105)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable.run(DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable.java:82)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

Our AmazonS3 client is configured as follows:

```
@Bean
@Primary
open fun amazonS3(awsCredentialsProvider: AWSCredentialsProvider): AmazonS3 {
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withClientConfiguration(
                ClientConfiguration()
                    .withTcpKeepAlive(true)
                    .withRequestTimeout(MAX_TIMEOUT)
                    .withSocketTimeout(MAX_TIMEOUT)
            )
            .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
            .build()
}
```

We are currently using the Spring resourceLoader to reference the S3 file inputstreams

```
resourceLoader.getResource("s3://%s".formatted(filename));
```

Any help or guidance with this would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

We have tried turning on TcpKeepAlive and have expanded our timeouts for the S3 client with no luck. I am thinking the problem may be on the aws side of things since it all works fine locally. I have attempted some retry logic when reading the files using a custom retry reader implementation for spring batch, but that failed to retry the connection to aws and failed fast anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the file from S3 to a local temp file first, then process that local temp file when updating the database.

Comment: Thanks for this! I wanted to do that as a last resort, but after exhausting all other attempts, this was the way! Ended up grabbing the input streams of the s3 files for the import, created temp files from them to use through the import process and then created a delete step to clean them up in case the deleteOnExit functionality failed for some reason or we had a long running instance in the future. 

Thank you again!